# How can I traverse and extract data using Haskell xml cursors?

Tags: xml, haskell

Using the Haskell [xml](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml) library by Galois Inc., I want to traverse XML using the [cursors](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/xml/1.3.13/doc/html/Text-XML-Light-Cursor.html) interface, without using monads.

And I want to check the tag name, tag attributes and text data enclosed by the tag.

How can I do this? Any examples?

To move the cursor, I could use `nextDF` to do depth-first left-to-right traversal. After moving the `Cursor`, I can use `toTree` to get `Content`, but from there, how do I convert to `Element` and then from `getTag`, use the contents within `Tag` to get tag name, tag attributes and text data enclosed by the tag?

The example should preferably include the opening of the file and then using the cursors interface.